# MYSQL: Multiple Table Join - Conditional on previous join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
    MEMBERS_TABLE

    member_id
    ---------------------------------------------
    1


    ACCOUNTS_TABLE

    account_id  member_id
    ---------------------------------------------
    1               1


    INVESTMENTS_TABLE

    investment_id   account_id
    ---------------------------------------------
    1               1
    2               1


    FUNDS_TABLE

    fund_id     investment_id
    ---------------------------------------------
    1               1
    2               2
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    m.member_id,
    a.account_id, 
    i.investment_id, 
    f.fund_id, 
    COUNT(a.account_id) AS member_accounts_total, 
    COUNT(i.investment_id) AS member_investments_total, 
    COUNT(f.fund_id) AS member_funds_total 
FROM members AS m
    LEFT JOIN accounts AS a ON m.member_id = a.member_id
    LEFT JOIN investments AS i ON a.account_id = i.account_id
    LEFT JOIN funds AS f ON f.fund_id = i.fund_id
```

**I would like to see the following results:**
member_accounts_total: 1
member_investments_total: 2
member_funds_total: 2

**Instead, I am getting these results:**
member_accounts_total: 2
member_investments_total: 2
member_funds_total: 2

I really don't want to write multiple queries for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to change
`COUNT(a.account_id) AS member_accounts_total,`

to
`COUNT( distinct a.account_id) AS member_accounts_total,`

The reason you're getting 2 is because the left join on accounts to investments results in 2 records.  To get a distinct count of members you need to add well... distinct.

Note you may have problems with the other totals as well (Distinct may be needed there as well in the long run...)  say if a member had multiple accounts. you may get odd counts as well (if each account had the same investment... would you want to see the count only once or twice?

Comment: It never crossed my mind to add "DISTINCT" - ::rolls eyes::

Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Its one of the few times I personally let myself use distinct.  Otherwise Group by should be used.; but here, it doesn't make sense.